# OpenCV 2.4 Jpeg to PNG with alpha channel

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a JPEG and a Mask. I want to create a PNG with the three JPEG channels and the alpha channel should be the Mask. How can I achieve this with OpenCV?

Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for your answer, I found a second solution:

```
cv::Mat transparent( height, width, CV_8UC4);
cv::Mat srcImg[] = {JPEG_img, alpha_Mask};
int from_to[] = { 0,0, 1,1, 2,2, 3,3 };
cv::mixChannels( srcImg, 2, &transparent, 1, from_to, 4 );
```

This works perfect, not sure which solution is better.

Comment: Indeed, I was kinda lazy to check mixChannels documentation before answering, split/merge is straightforward. But mixChannels is probably faster, since you dont need the temporary matrices

Comment: Yes, you are probably right, so I will mark this answer as the correct one. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> channels;
cv::split(jpgImage, channels);
channels.push_back(mask);
cv::Mat bgraImage;
cv::merge(channels, bgrAImage);
```

Documentation for [split and merge functions](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=merge#cv.Merge)