# How to right way to convert OpenCV code in JavaCV (mixChannels)

Tags: opencv, javacv

I have the same goal as the person who asked [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12820283/opencv-2-4-jpeg-to-png-with-alpha-channel)

> I have a JPEG and a Mask. I want to create a PNG with the three JPEG
>   channels and the alpha channel should be the Mask. How can I achieve
>   this with OpenCV?

But I don't know how to convert C++ code into JavaCV. All my attempts were unsuccessful

This is C++ code:

```cpp
cv::Mat transparent( height, width, CV_8UC4);
cv::Mat srcImg[] = {JPEG_img, alpha_Mask};
int from_to[] = { 0,0, 1,1, 2,2, 3,3 };
cv::mixChannels( srcImg, 2, &transparent, 1, from_to, 4 );
```

My implementation is:

```java
IplImage effect = opencv_imgcodecs.cvLoadImage(pathToEffect, opencv_imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
IplImage mask = opencv_imgcodecs.cvLoadImage(pathToMask, opencv_imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

CvMat matEffect = new CvMat(effect);
CvMat matMask = new CvMat(mask);
CvMat transparent = new CvMat(matEffect.size());

int from_to[] = { 0,0, 1,1, 2,2, 3,3 };

org.bytedeco.javacpp.helper.opencv_core.CvArr[] srcImg = {matEffect, matMask};
org.bytedeco.javacpp.helper.opencv_core.CvArr[] dstImg = {transparent};

opencv_core.cvMixChannels(srcImg, 2, dstImg, 1, from_to, 4);
```

But I get this error:

```java
OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Unknown array type) in cv::cvarrToMat, file src\matrix.cpp, line 893
```

Comment: First, you need to install OpenCV for Java in your system http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/java_eclipse/java_eclipse.html. Have you done it yet?

Comment: @Leo Yes, I have installed JavaCV and OpenCV. Both works fine

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't have OpenCV installed, in this computer but I have translated the C++ version to Java. It should work. If Core.mixchannels gives errors the try to change to cv::.

```
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;

public class Hello
{
   public static void main( String[] args )
   {

    Mat transparent( height, width, CV_8UC4);
    Mat [] srcImg = {JPEG_img, alpha_Mask};
    int [] from_to = { 0,0, 1,1, 2,2, 3,3 };
    //Core.mixChannels( srcImg, 2, &transparent, 1, from_to, 4 );
cvMixChannels(srcImg, 2, &transparent, 1, from_to, 4); // edit
       }
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. mixChannels do not have such constructor

Comment: I saw you are using cvFunctions; I have edited my answer with the apropriate function as it states in the documentation: http://www.mon-club-elec.fr/mes_docs/my_javacv_javadoc/com/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core.html#cvMixChannels%28com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.CvArr%5B%5D,%20int,%20com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.CvArr%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%5B%5D,%20int%29